# What is the best approach to navigate between tabs IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, navigation, ionic3

What is the best approach to navigate between tabs IONIC 3 in the same page.

I have a page called "Tasks", it has two main tabs:

- My Tasks
- All Tasks

each tab should return a different view than the other , so what's the best way to switch between those tabs' views while I am on the Tasks page ?

Here's an image shows what I have

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `<ion-segments>` and `[ngSwitch]`

Answer (score 0):

I think **ion-segment** will complete your requirement. Here is small example or you can refer [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/)

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-dark">

  <ion-segment ng-model="categories" full="true"  assertive>
  <ion-segment-button value="movies">
    Movies
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="series">
    Series
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="animation">
    Animate
  </ion-segment-button>

</ion-segment>
  </div>
<ion-content class="has-header">

  <div ng-switch="categories">

    <ion-list ng-switch-when="movies">
      <ion-item>
        Batman Begins
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Transporter
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Million Dollar Baby
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list ng-switch-when="series">
      <ion-item>
        Game of Thrones
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Daredevil
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Arrow
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-list ng-switch-when="animation">
      <ion-item>
        Ice Age
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Lion King
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Up
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```